# MDX Command for get YYYYMM

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx

I wrote a code to get this year and last year data using MDX in named sets.
Now I want to get this month and last month data, I am using Monthkey, 'YYYYMM'

my code is

```
{strtomember(
   "[Time].[Month Key].[" + cstr(year(dateadd('yyyy'+'mm',-1,now()))) +"]")
     : strtomember("[Time].[Month Key].[" + cstr(year(now())) +"]"
 )} ;
```

I need to change this to get this month and last month data with format of 'YYYYMM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would maybe use `strToSet` and don't forget your ampersands if you are using keys:

```
STRTOSET(
       "[Time].[Month Key].&[" 
           + CSTR(YEAR(DATEADD("M",-1,now()))) 
           + CSTR(MONTH(DATEADD("M",-1,now()))) 
        + "] : "
        + "[Time].[Month Key].&[" 
           + CSTR(YEAR(now())) 
           + CSTR(MONTH(now())) 
        + "]"
     );
```

Comment: this is working fine, but i need to connect with power BI, Named sets not support in Power bi, how can I get sum value of this month and last month using this named set and calculated measure. then i can connect with power bi